# Bootstrap Collapse element works in development but not production for Yii

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii2

I have the following collapse element that works in development but not production. (This is the HAML.)

```
  %button.btn.btn-success{'data-toggle' => "collapse", 'data-target' => "#newAd"} Create Ad
  .collapse#newAd
    -echo $view->render('_ad_form.haml', ['model'=>$model, 'action'=>'create-ad'])
```

Here is `assets/AppAssets.php`

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset'
```

Here is `config/assets-prod.php`

```
* This file is generated by the "yii asset" command.
* DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
...
 'yii\\bootstrap\\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
    'sourcePath' => null,
    'js' => [],
    'css' => [],
    'depends' => [
        'yii\\web\\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\\bootstrap\\BootstrapAsset',
        'all',
```

Here is the HTML source in production:

```
<script src="/assets/all-23d7e97aa4f8e635f58d3948e6d74143.js?v=1437530120"></script>
```

Here is the HTML source in development (among many other JS files):

```
<script src="/project/web/assets/33398a2a/js/bootstrap.js?v=1433622294"></script>
```

Collapse says it needs the Transitions plugin:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

However it says `bootstrap.js` already includes it.

When I click the button, the attributes of the HTML do change, but the form does not appear. Before:

```
<button class="btn btn-success collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#newAd" aria-expanded="false">Create Ad</button>
<div class="collapse" id="newAd" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
```

After:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#newAd" aria-expanded="true">Create Ad</button>
<div class="collapse in" id="newAd" aria-expanded="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your never going to believe this, but the `<div>` had a giant CSS definition with `display:none` and a selector of `#newAd` out of thousands. The source of this definition was a mysterious `<style type="text/css"></style>` which was empty. It was because of AdBlock. Even though it didn't show a number for ads blocked, when I paused it, it worked.